# How to write an int into System.Span, i.e the revers of int.Parse(span)?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I need to write and read big CSV (comma separated value) files, which basically contain integer values converted to strings. For reading such files efficiently, .Net Core has introduced a new `Parse` method for the type `int`:

```
public static int Parse (ReadOnlySpan<char> s,
  System.Globalization.NumberStyles style = 
  System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer, IFormatProvider provider = null);
```

This allows to use a `StreamReader` writing the characters of the file into a character array. My program has then to find the positions of the separation characters, creating a `ReadOnlySpan` containing the characters between 2 separators and then converting them into an `int`, without creating first a `string` out of these characters. Since my files contain millions of values, avoiding creating millions of `strings` should result in faster file reading. I hope.

But how about writing the `int` values as `strings` to the file ? Traditionally, it would be done like this:

```
var int1 = 1;
var int2 = 2;
streamWriter.WriteLine(int1.ToString() + "," + int2.ToString());
```

Again, for each `int` a `string` gets created and then another `string` for each line. This will create millions of strings that need to be garbage collected.

I would prefer something like that:

```
char[] charArray = getEmptyCharArray();
var span = new Span<char>(charArray);
int length1 = span.Write(int1);
charArray[length1] = ',';
span = span.Slice(length1 + 1);
int length2 = span.Write(int2);
streamWriter.Write(charArray, 0, length1 + 1 + length2);
```

`getEmptyCharArray()` provides a character array which gets reused.

Unfortunately, `Span` has no `Write()` function :-(

So the question is: How can I write an `int` (or `DateTime` or `Decimal` or ...) into a `Span` without generating any garbage collected objects (strings) ?

Note that any answer given before 2018 is probably not what is needed here, because `System.Span` got only introduced in .NET Core 2.1. Also note that the question here is about `System.Span` and not the HTML Span or any other Span.

Comment: The problem is allocating on the heap since you want to have full control on the memory and when it is freed.Have you considered using `stackalloc` ? For more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/stackalloc). Also you could use `System.Array.Buffers` which would reuse the same memory

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian: the problem is how to write an integer into a char[]) (i.e. a buffer) without actually creating a string object, which will reside on the heap. stackalloc and System.Array.Buffers do not prevent that int.ToString() will generate a string. But which other method can be used ? It seems strange that there is an int.Parse() for Span, but not a int.ToSpan()

Comment: I think you might get better answers if you ask this on the corefx repo on GitHub.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from Ian Kent, I asked on https://gitter.im/dotnet/corefx and they knew the answer. It's embarrassingly simple:

```
var i = 1;
Span<char> span = new char[100];
var ok = i.TryFormat(span, out var charsWritten);
```

Since I didn't find this answer for some days and I wanted to move on with my code, I wrote my own method, but using char[] instead of Span. I measured with BenchmarkRunner the speed of the different methods to write a 50 megabyte CSV file with 7'000'000 ints:

**60 ms: Writing the same constant string. This gives a base line how long DotNet needs just to write the file**

for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    streamWriter.WriteLine("1;12;123;1234;12345;123456;1234567;12345678;123;");
  }

**610 ms: Using ToString()**

for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
    streamWriter.WriteLine($"{i};{i+1};{i+2};{i+3};{i+4};{i+5};{i+6};");
  }

**308 ms: Using TryFormat(Span)**

**185 ms: Using my own method and char[]**

It's amazing that the string conversations take 10 times longer than writing the actual file. I would have expected that the harddisk is much slower than any software.

We are told that Span will solve many performance problems. Not by much. It seems it would have been better if they would use char[].

**Span test code**

```
public void WriteTo4() {
  var PathFileName = directoryInfo.FullName + @"\Test1.csv";
  using (var fileStream = new FileStream(PathFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, bufferSize, FileOptions.SequentialScan)) {
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream)) {
      var lineBuffer = new char[100];
      Span<char> span = lineBuffer;
      for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        var ok = i.TryFormat(span, out var charsWritten);
        lineBuffer[charsWritten++] = ';';
        var span1 = span[charsWritten..];
        ok = (i+1).TryFormat(span1, out charsWritten);
        span1[charsWritten++] = ';';
        span1 = span1[charsWritten..];
        ok = (i+2).TryFormat(span1, out charsWritten);
        span1[charsWritten++] = ';';
        span1 = span1[charsWritten..];
        ok = (i+3).TryFormat(span1, out charsWritten);
        span1[charsWritten++] = ';';
        span1 = span1[charsWritten..];
        ok = (i+4).TryFormat(span1, out charsWritten);
        span1[charsWritten++] = ';';
        span1 = span1[charsWritten..];
        ok = (i+5).TryFormat(span1, out charsWritten);
        span1[charsWritten++] = ';';
        span1 = span1[charsWritten..];
        ok = (i+6).TryFormat(span1, out charsWritten);
        span1[charsWritten++] = ';';

        var ca = lineBuffer[..(lineBuffer.Length - span1.Length + charsWritten)];
        streamWriter.WriteLine(lineBuffer, 0, lineBuffer.Length - span1.Length + charsWritten);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Test code using char[]**

```
public void WriteTo3() {
  var PathFileName = directoryInfo.FullName + @"\Test1.csv";
  using (var fileStream = new FileStream(PathFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, bufferSize, FileOptions.SequentialScan)) {
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream)) {
      var lineBuffer = new char[100];
      for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        var index = 0;
        lineBuffer.Write3(i, ref index);
        lineBuffer[index++] = ';';
        lineBuffer.Write3(i+1, ref index);
        lineBuffer[index++] = ';';
        lineBuffer.Write3(i+2, ref index);
        lineBuffer[index++] = ';';
        lineBuffer.Write3(i+3, ref index);
        lineBuffer[index++] = ';';
        lineBuffer.Write3(i+4, ref index);
        lineBuffer[index++] = ';';
        lineBuffer.Write3(i+5, ref index);
        lineBuffer[index++] = ';';
        lineBuffer.Write3(i+6, ref index);
        lineBuffer[index++] = ';';
        streamWriter.WriteLine(lineBuffer, 0, index);
      }
    }
  }
}


public static void Write3(this char[] charArray, int i, ref int index) {
  if (i<0) {
    charArray[index++] = '-';
    i = -i;
  }
  int start = index;

  while (i>9) {
    charArray[index++] = (char)((i % 10) + '0');
    i /= 10;
  }
  charArray[index++] = (char)(i + '0');
  var end = index-1;
  while (end>start) {
    var temp = charArray[end];
    charArray[end--] = charArray[start];
    charArray[start++] = temp;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you try parsing the `int` directly to a `char` array via passing through all digits , converting them to `char`-s and storing them directly to the destination.

```
public static ReadOnlySpan<char> ToSpan(int src)
        {
            int len = GetLength(src);
            Span<char> chars = new char[len];
            for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
            {
                chars[i]= (char)((Math.Floor(src / Math.Pow(10, (chars.Length - i - 1))) % 10) + 48);
            }
            return chars;

            static int GetLength(int src)
            {
                int len = 0;
                while (src > 0)
                {
                    src = src / 10;
                    len++;
                }
                return len;
            }

        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int original = 3334;
            var data = ToSpan(original);
            var copy= int.Parse(data);
            Console.WriteLine(copy);
        }
```

**P.S**

1. The bad part is that you need to iterate first on the `int` in order to get the length of the destination.
2. You can surely do some optimizations regarding the way i convert from a digit to a char ,and maybe also the way i segregate the digits.

Comment: I actually did write my own methods to write to Span. But since Microsoft provides a int i = int.Parse(Span), there should also be the reverse method available like i.Write(Span) or something. I don't need just to store int, but also double, Decimal, DateTime, etc. and I would prefer if I don’t have to write all these methods. My guess is that this functionality is somewhere available in .Net Core, but where ?

Comment: Some hints how to improve your code, but don't actually do it. One should not create an char[] in the method and return it as Span, but accept a  Span as method parameter, meaning the same char[] gets used millions of times instead of using each time a new one. If the Span is big enough just keep writing Span[index++] = (char)((i % 10) + '0'); followed by i /= 10; Of course, in the end you have to reverse the digits. And remember to handle negative number. As you can see, even implementing for int is a challenge, but the other types are even worse.

Comment: You accept a `Span` in your chain of operations, but don't forget that `Span` is something like a representation of a chunk of existing memory.That memory would be allocated somewhere.In your case , i supposed you would get the `int` as the parameter.If you would send a `Span` you would still allocate the `char` array somewhere higher in the hierarchy.Am i wrong in my assumption ?

Comment: I would create one char[] and then use it for every single line of the millions I have to read.

Comment: Ok fair point , but that means when your buffer is smaller then the target string , you would chunk the source.